# Simplify: $S=3^{1/3}\cdot 7^{1/4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

> Simplify: $$S=3^{1/3}\cdot7^{1/4}$$

How is it possible to simplify this?  The exponents are completely different.

Comment: Isn't it already simplified enough? Or perhaps you want to have something like, $$3^{1/3}\cdot 7^{1/4}=\left(3^{4}\right)^{1/12}                                                                                                                                   \cdot\left(7^{3}\right)^{1/12}=\left(3^4\cdot7^3\right)^{1/12}.$$

Comment: The issue isn't that the exponents are different, but that $ \ 3 \ $ and $ \ 7 \ $ have no common factors.  So you can make other sorts of arrangements of the expression, but none of them would really be called "simpler".  (You would only get substantial "simplification" if one of the bases were an integral or fractional power of the other one, for example, if the expression were $ \ 4^{1/3} \ \cdot \ 8^{1/4} \ $ .)

Comment: I agree with @Workaholic except that some people might consider $\sqrt[12]{27783}$ even more simplified.  (I personally prefer Workaholic's version or the version in the question.)

Comment: I (personally) _hate_ this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

it is impossible to simplify this (you wrote the reason).

only you can write this as $\sqrt[12]{3^4\cdot 7^3}$

Comment: The reason written by OP is wrong. See @RecklessReckoner's comment above.

Answer (score 0):

$3=7×(3/7)$ therfore $3^{1/3}=(3/7)^{1/3}*7^{1/3} $ therfore $3^{1/3}*7^{1/4} =(3/7)^{1/3}*7^{1/3} *7^{1/4} = (3/7)^{1/3}*7^{7/12} $

the final term still has two bases to two exponents but I find it a simplified form to work with.  Simplification to one term to a power is impossible due to 3 and 7 are coprime. In fact they are simply prime.

Comment: ?? $7 \times 0.5 = 3.5$, not 3.

Comment: wow can't believe I made that simple of arithmetic mistake let me correct